# jupyter notebook is giving error in installation. The details are in the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm writing `pip install jupyterlab` as the cmd command. Loading, but two warnings are coming. then the installation keeps saying successful. But when I tried to start it gives the error.

I tried to install it before, but I could not get over this error somehow. I would be glad if you help.

```
C:\Users\HASAN>pip install jupyterlab
Collecting jupyterlab
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2c/89/a4e048f198867f19d2a9f40d08c946d760ab06dd39d774940a20da47b5f9/jupyterlab-1.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2>=2.10 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jupyterlab) (2.10.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado!=6.0.0,!=6.0.1,!=6.0.2 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jupyterlab) (6.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook>=4.3.1 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jupyterlab) (6.0.1)
Collecting jupyterlab-server~=1.0.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/78/98/5b87b9d38176bd98f23b58a8fb730e5124618d68571a011abbd38ad4a842/jupyterlab_server-1.0.6-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jinja2>=2.10->jupyterlab) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2.1 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (18.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.4.0 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (5.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.3.1 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (5.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (5.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.1 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.2.0)
Collecting json5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/44/062543d4a6718f99d82e5ecf9140dbdee8a03122f2c34fbd0b0609891707/json5-0.8.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=3.0.1 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jupyterlab-server~=1.0.0->jupyterlab) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2.1->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2.1->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jupyter-core>=4.4.0->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (225)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=5.0.0 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipykernel->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (7.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.3.1->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<2,>=0.8.1 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pywinpty>=0.5; os_name == "nt" in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from terminado>=0.8.1->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.5.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1->jupyterlab-server~=1.0.0->jupyterlab) (0.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1->jupyterlab-server~=1.0.0->jupyterlab) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1->jupyterlab-server~=1.0.0->jupyterlab) (41.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1->jupyterlab-server~=1.0.0->jupyterlab) (0.23)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from importlib-metadata->jsonschema>=3.0.1->jupyterlab-server~=1.0.0->jupyterlab) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parso>=0.5.0 in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools in c:\users\hasan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from zipp>=0.5->importlib-metadata->jsonschema>=3.0.1->jupyterlab-server~=1.0.0->jupyterlab) (7.2.0)
Installing collected packages: json5, jupyterlab-server, jupyterlab
  WARNING: The script pyjson5.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\HASAN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts jlpm.exe, jupyter-lab.exe, jupyter-labextension.exe and jupyter-labhub.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\HASAN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed json5-0.8.5 jupyterlab-1.1.4 jupyterlab-server-1.0.6

C:\Users\HASAN>jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: What about `jupyter lab`? Also, maybe you need to `pip install jupyter` as well?

Comment: could you try 'python -m jupyterlab lab'?